# 2d array inside another array?

Tags: java, arrays, math, matrix

Is there anyway to make an array hold 2d array?

I want to somehow hold the value of matrixFinal based on what the user enters so I can later use it. I think I'd be able to do this if I can hold these values in an array but these are 2d arrays...

How would I go about doing this?

```
public class Driver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, j, k, l ;
    int sum = 0 ;
    int matrixAColumnSize   ;
    int matrixARowSize      ;
    int raiseByPower        ;


    // Querying user
    matrixARowSize      =   Tools.queryForInt("Enter the row size of Matrix A: ") ;
    matrixAColumnSize   =   Tools.queryForInt("Enter the column size of Matrix A: ") ;
    Tools.verifyMatrixSize(matrixAColumnSize, matrixARowSize) ;  // Verification of matrix size 10x10 max
    Tools.verifyMultiplication(matrixARowSize, matrixAColumnSize) ; // Verification of matrix size
    raiseByPower        =   Tools.queryForInt("By what power would you like to raise the matrix? ") ; 
    Tools.verifyMatrixPower(raiseByPower) ; // Verification of power. ^6 max

    //Making matrices
    int matrixA[][] = new int[matrixARowSize][matrixAColumnSize] ;
    int matrixFinal[][] = new int [matrixARowSize][matrixAColumnSize] ; 

    // Querying for elements of Matrix A
            for (i = 0; i < matrixARowSize; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < matrixAColumnSize; j++) {
                    matrixA[i][j] = Tools.queryForInt("Enter element in Matrix A" + (i+1) + "," + (j+1) + " :" ) ; }}

    // Multiplying matrices
            if (raiseByPower == 1) {
                for (i = 0; i < matrixARowSize; i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < matrixAColumnSize; j++) {
                        matrixFinal[i][j] = matrixA[i][j] ;
                    }
                }

            } else if (raiseByPower == 2) {
            for (i = 0; i < matrixARowSize; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < matrixAColumnSize; j++) 
                {
                    for (k = 0; k < matrixARowSize; k++) 
                    {
                        sum = sum + matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] ;
                    }

                    matrixFinal[i][j] = sum ;
                    sum = 0 ;
                }
            }

            } else if (raiseByPower == 3) {
                for (i = 0; i < matrixARowSize; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < matrixAColumnSize; j++) 
                    {
                        for (k = 0; k < matrixARowSize; k++) 
                        {
                            sum += matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] ;
                            sum = 0 ;
                        }
                        matrixFinal[i][j] = sum ;

                    }
                    }
            } else if (raiseByPower == 4) {
                for (i = 0; i < matrixARowSize; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < matrixAColumnSize; j++) 
                    {
                        for (k = 0; k < matrixARowSize; k++) 
                        {
                            sum += matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] ;
                        }
                        matrixFinal[i][j] = sum ;
                        sum = 0 ;
            }
                }} else if ( raiseByPower == 5) {
                    for (i = 0; i < matrixARowSize; i++)
                    {
                        for (j = 0; j < matrixAColumnSize; j++) 
                        {
                            for (k = 0; k < matrixARowSize; k++) 
                            {
                                sum += matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] ;
                            }
                            matrixFinal[i][j] = sum ;
                            sum = 0 ;
                }
                }
                } else if ( raiseByPower == 6) {
                    for (i = 0; i < matrixARowSize; i++)
                    {
                        for (j = 0; j < matrixAColumnSize; j++) 
                        {
                            for (k = 0; k < matrixARowSize; k++) 
                            {
                                sum += matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] * matrixA[i][j] ;
                            }
                            matrixFinal[i][j] = sum ;
                            sum = 0 ;
                }
                }
                } 

            System.out.println("Matrix A to the power of " + raiseByPower + " is: ") ;

            for (i = 0; i < matrixARowSize; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < matrixAColumnSize; j++) 
                    System.out.print(matrixFinal[i][j] + "\t") ;

                System.out.println();
            }
```

} }

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  How would you do this in an array?  Do you want one of the entries in `matrixA` to point to `matrixFinal`?  Could you delete the matrix multiplication part from this code, since it doesn't add anything.

Comment: I want to create an array that will hold all 6 different matrixFinal[][] (I think I would have to change each of their name) and then use user input to point to it. @Teepeemm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest arrays as much as you want so something like int[][][] is certainly possible, which is an array of 2d arrays.

Well, you already have an int[][] so you can make an

```
int[][][] container = new int[numberofmatrixes][matrixsize][matrixsize];
```

and then add your matrixA or matrixFinal:

```
container[index] = matrixA;
```

and get values from matrixA:

```
int a = container[index][index2][index3];
```

where before you would have used

```
int a = matrixA[index2][index3];
```

You treat the 'container' array like any other array so the first matrix would be added at container[0], the second at container[1] and so on. You have to remember which matrix is at what index yourself.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for... but can you explain a little more?

Comment: One more question, how would I add them all once I have them? For instance if I wanted to add the first matrix + second matrix + third etc

Answer (score -1):

In C, a 2d array and a 1d array are the "same thing", in that they are all calculated offsets from some memory address (a pointer, p). For example, to get the 5th element of an int array on a 32-bit compiler, you'd multiple (5-1)x4 and add that to the address p, which is written as p[4] (assuming that the type of p is a pointer to int and int is a 4-byte word). In Java, if p is an array of int, then you can likewise access the 5th one via p[4].

In C, you can access a 2d array in much the same way, e.g. p[4][2]. For example, see: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm

The way it works in C is that the first number is multiplied by the size of the array in rows, then added to the second number, then multiplied by the element size. So p[4][2] is ((void*)p)+168 if the array is 10x10 and the "int" (aka word size) is 32 bits, i.e. it's the 42nd element.

Now to do a "two-dimensional array on an array" in Java is a little more complex, because the compiler doesn't do that math for you, but you can do it. Just make a class called Matrix, take rows & columns in the constructor, create the underlying 1-dimensional array, and have two methods called:

```
public T get(int row, int column)
put(int row, int column, T value)
```

etc.